# How to strip HTML tags using a black list in PHP?

Tags: php, parsing, html-parsing, strip-tags

PHP `strip_tags` use a whitelist for skip some tags that you don't want were get rid. Anybody knows some implementation but using a blacklist instead of a whitelist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple compound regex search would work (if this is still about your previous issue):

```
$html =
preg_replace("#</?(font|strike|marquee|blink|del)[^>]*>#i", "", $html);
```

Comment: please, explain this part: [^>]*

Comment: @texai: `[^>]*` is a common method for matching everything inside of HTML tags. It matches any number of characters that are **not** a closing `>` angle bracket. The regex part `[^...]` means a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try this function posted by LWC on php.net - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php#96483

```
<?php
function strip_only($str, $tags, $stripContent = false) {
    $content = '';
    if(!is_array($tags)) {
        $tags = (strpos($str, '>') !== false ? explode('>', str_replace('<', '', $tags)) : array($tags));
        if(end($tags) == '') array_pop($tags);
    }
    foreach($tags as $tag) {
        if ($stripContent)
             $content = '(.+</'.$tag.'[^>]*>|)';
         $str = preg_replace('#</?'.$tag.'[^>]*>'.$content.'#is', '', $str);
    }
    return $str;
}

$str = '<font color="red">red</font> text';
$tags = 'font';
$a = strip_only($str, $tags); // red text
$b = strip_only($str, $tags, true); // text
?>
```