# CKEditor remove tags server side

Tags: php, ckeditor

We use CKEditor for admins to write articles but also for frontend redactors. Because CKEditor is only JS we want to add some server-side tags stripping to be sure not to leave some  or  or others bad ones...

The php function strip_tags() make it possible to allow some tags but we prefer to be able to have a blacklist. Also it didn't look very effective.

Do you know a good way ?

Thanks

EDIT : The solution given by @ErwinMoller delete tags but not the content within it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to strip HTML tags using a black list in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996977/how-to-strip-html-tags-using-a-black-list-in-php)

Comment: @ErwinMoller : I read that but wanted to know there was a "better" solution.

Answer (score 2):

There's no easy and safe way of allowing *some* (safe) HTML in PHP. It's simple to strip all HTML, but once you want to start allowing *some* HTML you run into all kinds of security issues.

Using a library such as [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) is the best way to go, and it gives you the ability to whitelist or blacklist tags and attributes at the same time as it prevents malicious code.

Answer (score -1):

You can do one thing with strip_tags().

please try justify css on `<p> tag`. it will be helpful for your view.

Or you can use FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING for filtered string from tags.
please check below code.

```
$string = filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Comment: As I said we don't want to use strip_tags. Some reading : https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/nj5t0/what_everyone_should_know_about_strip_tags/

Comment: please check above modified answer