# Use a function in twig like striptag but instead of whitelist tags, I want to blacklist tag(s)

Tags: twig

Say I have a textfield that the user can fill.
I want to strip the `<a>` element in twig. How do I do this?

I can use

```
{{ some_html|striptags('<a>') }}
```

This would allow/preserve the `<a>` element. But what if I only want to remove an `<a>` element?

Comment: U'd need to extend `twig` with a `Twig_Function` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996977/how-to-strip-html-tags-using-a-black-list-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that it's a good idea to use a blacklist instead of a whitelist?

If you are, it's easy to create a custom Twig filter using [this code by Michael Berkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072327/strip-tags-function-blacklist-rather-than-whitelist/7072410#7072410) as a reference:

```
$twig->addFilter(new Twig_Filter('removetags', function($html, ...$tags) {
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML('<body>' . $html . '</body>', LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $elements = iterator_to_array($dom->getElementsByTagName($tag));

        foreach ($elements as $el) {
            $el->parentNode->removeChild($el);
        }
    }

    return str_replace(['<body>', '</body>'], '', $dom->saveHTML());
}));
```

Then in Twig:

```
{% set html = 'hello <a href="#">world</a>, <em>how</em> <a>are</a> you?' %}

{{ html|raw }}
{{ html|removetags('a')|raw }}
{{ html|removetags('em')|raw }}
{{ html|removetags('a', 'em')|raw }}
```

The above produces this:

```
hello <a href="#">world</a>, <em>how</em> <a>are</a> you?

hello , <em>how</em>  you?

hello <a href="#">world</a>,  <a>are</a> you?

hello ,   you?
```

Some notes:

- I named the filter as `removetags` because [`striptags` is a built-in Twig filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/striptags.html).
- I used `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD`, because otherwise you'd get `<!DOCTYPE html ...>` and other extra tags in the output. [See documentation of `DOMDocument::loadHTML`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) for more info.
- I wrapped the loaded HTML into `<body>` tags and later removed them. Otherwise you'd get an extra `<p>` element in the output or the output could be broken in some other way. Kudos to [this comment](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php#121444). (Using `<html>` tags didn't work for me, so I used `<body>` tags.)

Comment: Yes I'm sure I want to blacklist. I've already got secure output from the cms. I just want to remove the <a> element.
I can see there is not a simple function in twig already. So I'll accept this answer. It is clear and tells me ( and others ) how to do this.